# Firebase A/B testing: Is there a way for a backend event to be used as a goal metric in firebase a/b testing

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-ab-testing

I have a firebase a/b testing setup with goal metrics set to events sent from the android app, and events sent from the backend.

The a/b test results appears to show the conversion from the android app events, but always shows zero when looking at the conversion from events sent from backend. So it looks like no users did the backend events.

But when we looked at analytics dashboard, the backend events are correctly being sent and recorded in firebase analytics.

It appears that the a/b testing dashboard cannot associate the events from the backend to the same user in the experiments. Thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like you're already sending the data from Android app and backend correctly to the same Firebase analytics project which is necessary for sure. I'd check how do you identify the user - you probably need to set User ID to the same value in both app vs backend events.